# the router link doesn't get new data added to database

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I am having a component **add.component.ts**

```
constructor(
    private studentService:StudentService,private departmentService:DepartmentService,private router:Router) { }
  departmentList:Department[];

  newStudent:Student = new Student(0,"","",0);

  addNewStudent(f){
    this.studentService.addNew(new Student(newStudent)).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.router.navigate(["/student"]);
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

that connect to a service to add new student in the database.*and it running so well, already tested before*
And here the html link that routerLink

```
<a routerLink="/student/add" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Add New Student</a>
```

and also have **student-index.component.ts** and that display all the student in a table getting that data from the same service

```
studentList:Student[];
  constructor(private studentService:StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentService.getAll().subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        this.studentList = data;
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

  }
```

and each one of them has his own routing link in the **app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
{path:"student",component:StudentIndexComponent,children:[
      {path:"add",component:AddComponent},
      ...
    ]},

...
```

and here i am trying to make the add and other children of student list.
and the service connect to a nodeJs project and retrieve the data from mongoDb
Every thing is working well. but when i use the addCompnent to add to the database and redirect to the */student* it retrieve the old data without adding the new list, although i force it to redirect to the action the bring the data from the database, and i must refresh the page to show the new data

Comment: I don't understand.. when you want to add something, shoulnd't you submit a form with the value, and then (eventualy) post the data to a service, that in turn will call a repository that will persist the data, or call an external API? how are you sending the data with the router like? using parameters? if so, where is the code that gets the parameters? Create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) with a working example so we can look at it.

Comment: @rmjoia i am using a reference to the form to get the data from it. and i send the send through the service to the database, and the other function must retrieve the data from the database. but it doesn't work and get the new data with it, it look like it save the data somewhere and some how don't execute the function but retrieve the old one.